# Where's this extra /home folder come from?

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs

My laptop's home drive is encrypted. When I run `cd / && ncdu` and navigate to /home, I see this:

> 50.0 GiB /.ecryptfs
> 50.0 GiB /dan
> 22.4 GiB /dan.GynX3uiX

I'm pretty sure that aint quite right. There's no other users on this laptop than mine. I gather, from googling, that ecryptfs can give the appearance of a doubled home drive, so that is probably the explanation behind the .ecryptfs folder. What I have no explanation for is dan.GynX3uiX - what might explain the presence of that folder? If I open it, it's not encrypted and seems to be an old snapshot of my normal home directory, so I suspect I've created it by mistake somehow and can safely delete it.

Comment: Before you pull the trigger, try running without it for a while: `sudo  chmod 000 /dan.GynX3uiX`. `sudo lsof +D /dan.GynX3uiX` first.

Comment: @waltinator smart man - that's a top idea thanks.